# Como centralizar um título no cabeçalho usando atributos de class?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Comecei a estudar *Bootstrap* agora e estou tendo problemas pra entender e modificar os códigos em *CSS* da pasta que baixei no site deles mesmo, então seria mais fácil editar na parte de *HTML*

Eu preciso centralizar o texto *CADASTRE-SE*, mas não estou conseguindo de jeito nenhum e nos arquivos de *CSS*, são feitas várias citações sobre a classe e parece que ela é sobrescrita várias vezes, então se eu mexer em um, preciso alterar os outros também.

[image: Site usando bootstrap]

```
<header class="masthead clearfix navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/drawing2.png" width="9%"/>
    </div>

    <div class="inner">
        <div class="nav justify-content-center m-auto">
            <h3 class="masthead-brand"> CADASTRE-SE </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Qual a versão do *Bootstrap* você está usando ?

Comment: Estou usando a versão "bootstrap-4.0.0-beta".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode centralizar o texto usando a classe `text-center` basta informar ela no atributo `class` da tag *H3* e no atributo `class` da tag *img* informar `img-fluid` e tirar o atributo `width`, crie também a *Folha de Estilo*:

```
<style>
img {
    max-width: 100%; /* largura máxima de 100% */
}
</style>
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<header class="masthead clearfix navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 logo">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png" class="img-fluid" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 inner">
        <div class="nav justify-content-center m-auto">
            <h3 class="masthead-brand text-center"> CADASTRE-SE </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Clique em `Página toda` para melhor visualização.

#### Referências

- [Responsive images](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#responsive-images)
- [Text alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment)

Comment: Ainda assim, não funcionou.  
Será que o fato de ter a imagem no canto superior a esquerda interfere em algo?

Comment: [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/249219/edit) sua pergunta e coloque o *CSS* que você criou, não do *Bootstrap*.

Comment: Então, não criei _CSS_ nenhum.

Comment: Sim, agora eu testei aqui, a imagem interfere, o correto é você criar colunas

Comment: Veja agora como ficou minha resposta.

Comment: Agradeço, eu definitivamente não sei usar a formatação de texto daqui.

Comment: Faça o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), também pode acessar a [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Tem um problema, ao mexer na tag <img> pra tentar redimensionar a logo, os ícones do formulario também têm seu tamanho alterado.

Comment: Você pode retirar o atributo `class` da imagem e colocar `width="9%` ou utilizar [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) para ícones, é preferivel você utilizar *Font Awesome*.